# build is continuing with next targets even if one target fails

Tags: apache, ant, installation, izpack, ant-contrib

I have an ant code which is executed on unix. In one of the target the build is failing , but in the console the next steps in current target are skipped but targets after the failed one are executing.

```
**BUILD FAILED**
/irb/cst/install/scripts/installer.xml:386: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/irb/cst/install/scripts/installer.xml:597: The following error occurred while executing this line:


Total time: 1 second
Starting process Finalize staging (10/13)
\t Installation type is UPGRADE \n
Buildfile: ./install/scripts/installer.xml

check-pf:
     [echo]  verifying whether Platform already extracted or not /irb/cst/cst2/workareas/schu/GUItest/STAGE
     [echo]  pf.present value true
     [echo]  (tmp.unpack.dir) Platform extracted at /irb/cst/cst2/workareas/schu/GUItest/TMP
```

in the above log, 1st target failed, but the build continues with second target.

```
<if>
                      <equals arg1="${commonCompareVersionsRC}" arg2="0"/>
                           <then>
                             <property name="buildstatus" value="true"/>
                             <echo> @@@ ${buildstatus} </echo>
                              <echo>ERROR - Cannot be Migrated backwards from higher version to lesser version.Exiting...</echo>
                            <var name="commonCompareVersionsRC" unset="true"/>
                             <fail message="Need to have a newer version for the @{component} package . Installed version:${@{component}_DBPKG_VERSION}, migrating to version:${Installingversion}"/>
                           </then>
                      </if>
```

Comment: Hows the ant snippet you've posted related to this ? Chances are you need to post a lot more of your ant file.

Comment: since you've tagged `IzPack`, is it possible that the successive targets (which are being executed even after Build failure) are being call through `AntActionsSpec.xml` ?

Comment: the AntActionSpec.xml calls an Installer.xml which has sequence of targets which are executing. One of the target in sequence is failing .the next targets in the sequence are executed even if one of the target is failed.